# secure or encrypt smarty plugins

Tags: php, smarty

I am working on CMS system using smarty. The one cms system could support multiple websites with multiple websites, multiple templates, multiple plugins and components...

Client can register and create his website using pre existing templates and choose components to display them on that template.

My Question is that How i can make those component secure or encrypted. so if client take his site away from the server to another server, he won't able to use those module, components etc. or atleast these would expire after certain time..

I am going to create these components using smarty plugins.

Is there any solution in php, smarty ?

Comment: Hm, that's pretty tough - as PHP is an interpreted language, the source code is also the executable code. You *could* encrypt the plugin files with some sort of server-specific key and decrypt them on execution, but this will slow down the execution of your program. I'm not aware of a pre-built solution which would allow this dynamically (i.e. for any file). How technically savvy do you expect your users to be? You could get away with putting the components into a directory that's readable by server, but not by CMS.

Comment: well my clients might not be that technical but the web developer who will shift the code from one server to another might be programer like us :) there are some server side program such as ioncube. but i don't want to go to that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to secure the file itself, you may just make those templates private :

Set up the include_path of your php environment to a private folder, thus, your application can use the files in this folder, templates included.
Your users however can't retrieve the files easily.

Comment: For this to work they still need to be accessible, so your clients will be able to get the contents anyway.

Comment: This is subjective indeed. My proposal is quick to setup, but any clients with some technical background can retrieve the code using a script...

Answer (score 1):

Zend Server offers such a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use something like the ionCube PHPEncoder which is able to do the job for Smarty (via a Patch), I would recommend you write a script that performs code obfuscation to your Smarty files to make it a real annoyance to de-obfuscate them. 
Ideally that would include variable obfuscation also but you then need to touch your PHP files also when handling the variables over to Smarty.

This is not great, but as said, when not using a real encoder there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

As before mentioned **IONCube** do the job well, but if you need some fast solution without crypt or embarrassing the code with such a tool, then you need to code something... I remenber sometime ago I did a kind of tool, I crypt the data, then put it inside a database and after a time I retrieve that data, off course checking the passphrase key. This is the way, but sometimes it can make your server very slow, specialy if you have a lot of users.

good Luck man!